# javascript push item into object by variable name

Tags: javascript

Sorry for the newbie question but I must be overlooking something. How do I set `obj.{this.name} = property` so obj.sandwich = off. My object would look something like:

```
obj { sandwich: off, soup: off }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/naaua4b5/

List of checkboxes:

```
<input type = "checkbox" name = "sandwich" />
<input type = "checkbox" name = "soup" />
```

js code:

```
var obj = {} ; 

$('input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').map(function()
{
     var item_name =  this.name;
     var value = 'off';
     obj.item_name = value;
}).get();

console.log (obj);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use bracket notation:

```
var obj = {} ; 
      $('input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)').map(function()
                {
                    var item_name =  this.name;
                    var value = 'off';
                    obj[item_name] = value;// <-brackets!
                }).get();
console.log (obj);
```

dot notation `obj.key` accesses an object using the literal "key" and, although the norm, can be limiting depending on what you want to do. Bracket notation `obj['key']` gives you a little more freedom where you can use a variable as the key (as in your case) or even throw crazy characters in there like `obj["I'm-Acrazy_Key"]`

Comment: Could you explain why bracket notation should be used over dot notation here?

Comment: Both conventions would work but one is preferred over the other; by explaining the preferred approach would increase the value of this answer.

Comment: why does the . notation not work in my loop and yet the bracket notation does?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I sometimes get excited and throw answers up. I've edited to explain myself better. @Undermine2k, the end result is that bracket notation allows you to use variables for your key.

Comment: There's an underscore in the variable name, dot notation doesn't like that. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets) for more details on dot vs bracket